# How to compare the entries in two tables?

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to find out if the following two tables have similar entries:

```
s1 = Table[Mod[3 807^r, 2017], {r, 0, 44}]

s2 = Table[Mod[45^q, 2017], {q, 1, 150}]
```

so I give the following command:

```
s = Flatten[Table[s1[[x]] == s2[[y]], {x, 1, 44}, {y, 1, 150}]]
```

But in this way I have to check with my own eyes all the `False` or `True` entries in table s....Is there a way to make Mathematica to do it for me? thanks

Comment: `Intersection[s1, s2]` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! If I may ask, how to find which entry of s1 has this common value?, @MarcoB

Comment: Index of common values in `s1`: `s1 // Position[Alternatives @@ Intersection[s1, s2]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More directly,

```
Clear["Global`*"]

{r, q, Mod[3 807^r, 2017]} /. 
 Solve[{Mod[3 807^r, 2017] == Mod[45^q, 2017], 0 <= r <= 44, 
   1 <= q <= 150}, {r, q}, Integers]

(* {{22, 112, 2016}, {31, 67, 202}, {40, 22, 1553}} *)
```